# Convert and Serve Image File via Published Web App in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, image, google-apps-script, jpeg, gif

I'm trying to use Apps Script as an image conversion API, using URL parameters like so:

```js
function doGet(request) {
  let source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request?.parameter?.url).getBlob();
  let converted = source.getAs(request?.parameter?.type);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(converted.getDataAsString()).downloadAsFile(converted.getName());
}

function test() {
  doGet({"parameter": {"url": "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/noaa/noaad1.gif", "type": "image/jpeg"}});
}
```

The resulting file resembles being correct, but is malformed.

[image: A screenshot of a text editor showing a lot of unicode characters in a malformed jpeg file]

Where am I going wrong? I've tried using `converted.getBytes()`, I've tried `converted.getDataAsString('UTF-8')` and `converted.getDataAsString('ASCII')`... I must be missing something obvious? I feel like I'm so close!

Comment: In the current stage, `ContentService.createTextOutput` is used for returning text content. When `ContentService.createTextOutput(converted.getDataAsString())` is used, the data is converted to string data. By this, when the original data is binary data, this cannot be correctly used. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, for example, how about returning the base64 data? By this, this can be also used as the data URL. But, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Why are you using a MIME type of JPEG when the image is a gif?

Comment: @Tedinoz I am specifying a URL to an image of a GIF, and what type I want to convert it _to_

Comment: @Tanaike I am trying to get the original image as a Blob, convert it to a JPEG (or other format) via the `Blob.getAs()` function, then return that to the requester. Is there no way to serve a Blob via Published Web App? I thought that's what `ContentService.downloadAsFile()` was for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Is there no way to serve a Blob via Published Web App?`, I think that in this case, Blob cannot be directly returned with `ContentService.createTextOutput` as I mentioned in my 1st comment. So, I proposed a workaround. I apologize for this.